# How to stop an infinite loop function called with myFunc &

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my bash script, I have a function that does one certain task in an infinite loop. To allow for the next part of my code to run at the same time, I run it with `myFunc &`.

How can I kill this function, when the rest of my program is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options. If this is your only background process then you can easily kill it with

```
kill %1
```

You can save the PID of the subshell:

```
myFunc &
myFunc_PID=$!
[...]
kill -HUP "$myFunc_PID"
```

You can also use

```
kill %myFunc
```

It makes sense to put the subshell killing in the EXIT handler:

```
trap 'kill %myFunc' EXIT
```